# Trying to find-and-replace decimal commas with decimal points in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I'm trying to replace decimal commas with decimal points in my MS Word 2007. The document clearly has numbers with decimal commas, for instance, `100,5%`.

I'm using the following line in "find":

> `([0-9]{1;}),([0-9]{1;})`

However, it fails to find the `100,5%` value (the value is in a table cell in the document). I wonder why.

My replace line would be

> `\1.\2`

Answer (score 2):

The search function will not allow you to search for commas that are part of a number (to my knowledge).

I run into this when working with documents that were written in French (commas instead of decimal points).

Copy the contents of the entire table and paste it into excel.  Then modify change the commas to periods in excel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADcdv5KyPII

Then copy and paste the data back into Word.

Comment: That's odd. I remember running this find and replace line against other Russian document a week ago, but without tables, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Oh, that's your first answer. Welcome to the Stack Exchange!

Comment: I found it: for some reason this combination works: find `<([0-9]{1;}),([0-9]{1;})>` and replace with `\1.\2`. Why the addition of the angle brackets changes Word's behaviour is beyond me.